# Creat android barcode reader to get database information

Tags: android, kotlin, barcode-scanner, ean-13

I want to create an android app by android studio to get information from barcode such as price and name.

the thing is i am new to this so i am asking if i can make a barcode reader that scans ean-13 barcode and get price and name from database like "Open Food Facts", the exact question is how can i make the barcode reader get the price and name ? do i have to link it with some kind of data base ?

btw i am using android studio with kotlin if it helps .
And this is my first topic, i don't know how things works here so if i did anything wrong please be free to point it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to link the bar code scanner with a database if you want to retrieve the information from a given barcode.

For instance, if you are scanning the QR code embedded in a book that has a unique ID, you will then need to have access to the database of all the books mapped with their relevant QR code ID.

Could you share your exact use case here as that might help us understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: We are still on the brainstorming phase, we hadn't draw any diagram yet, still our program is simple, capture ean 13 bar-code and present list of prices that user can pick one of it, still we don't know how to link the read from bar-code with the database , we intend to use fire-base to do this but the problem is the price and names.
you mention that you need to link to the relevant database, do you know a database that has price lists for famous items like notila and galacy and such ?

Comment: I doubt if you can find such a database. However, you can use firebase to manually create a mock API of your own using Firebase Realtime Database/ Firestore and that should work just fine.